# How to sort an arraylist on date?

Tags: c#

Code:

```
while ((linevalue = filereader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
      items.Add(linevalue);
}
filereader.Close();
items.Sort();
//To display the content of array (sorted)
IEnumerator myEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(myEnumerator.Current);
}
```

The program above displays all the values. How to extract only the dates and sort it in ascending order?

---

I am not let to work with linq, use the exception or threading or any other stuff. I have to stick with the File Stream, try to get my data out of the text file, sort and store it, so that i can retrieve it, view it and edit it and search for any particular date and see the date of joining records for that date. Can't figure out. Struggling

Comment: Why do you use an arraylist at all nowadays? Why don't you simply use `File.ReadAllLines` instead which returns a `String[]`? Even better,   load a `List<CustomClass>` where `CustomClass` has the properties above.

Comment: Are the "columns" in the text file delimited (e.g. tab)?

Comment: Also, don't use the enumerator directly, use foreach instead: `foreach(var item in items) Console.WriteLine(item);`

Comment: to emphasize @digEmAll's point - in addition to being extra code, you've actually *not implemented it fully* - technically, you also need to check if `myEnumerator` is `IDisposable`, and if so ensure you dispose it (for both success and failure) - `foreach` does a lot of good things for you. Additionally, `foreach` supports duck-typing, meaning: it can be more efficient than `IEnumerator`

Comment: No, its not like a tab.

Comment: @MartinSahner please try and put your comments under the appropriate post - this is getting very confusing

Answer (score 4):

Basically, don't try and work with the file as lines of text; separate that away, so that you have one piece of code which *parses* that text into typed records, and then process those upstream when you only need to deal with typed data.

For example (and here I'm assuming that the file is tab-delimited, but you could change it to be column indexed instead easily enough); look at how *little work* my `Main` method needs to do to work with the data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var item in ReadFile("my.txt").OrderBy(x => x.Joined))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Names);
        }
    }
    static readonly char[] tab = { '\t' };
    class Foo
    {
        public string Names { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public DateTime Joined { get; set; }
    }
    static IEnumerable<Foo> ReadFile(string path)
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            // skip the first line (headers), or exit
            if (reader.ReadLine() == null) yield break;

            // read each line
            string line;
            var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var parts = line.Split(tab);
                yield return new Foo
                {
                    Names = parts[0],
                    Age = int.Parse(parts[1], culture),
                    Designation = parts[2],
                    Joined = DateTime.Parse(parts[3], culture)
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a version (not quite as elegant, but working) that works on .NET 2.0 (and *probably* on .NET 1.1) using only ISO-1 language features; personally I think it would be silly to use .NET 1.1, and if you are using .NET 2.0, then `List<T>` would be vastly preferable to `ArrayList`. But this is "worst case":

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList items = ReadFile("my.txt");
        items.Sort(FooByDateComparer.Default);
        foreach (Foo item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Names);
        }
    }
    class FooByDateComparer : IComparer
    {
        public static readonly FooByDateComparer Default
            = new FooByDateComparer();
        private FooByDateComparer() { }
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return ((Foo)x).Joined.CompareTo(((Foo)y).Joined);
        }
    }

    static readonly char[] tab = { '\t' };
    class Foo
    {
        private string names, designation;
        private int age;
        private DateTime joined;
        public string Names { get { return names; } set { names = value; } }
        public int Age { get { return age; } set { age = value; } }
        public string Designation { get { return designation; } set { designation = value; } }
        public DateTime Joined { get { return joined; } set { joined = value; } }
    }
    static ArrayList ReadFile(string path)
    {
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            // skip the first line (headers), or exit
            if (reader.ReadLine() == null) return items;

            // read each line
            string line;
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(tab);
                Foo foo = new Foo();
                foo.Names = parts[0];
                foo.Age = int.Parse(parts[1], culture);
                foo.Designation = parts[2];
                foo.Joined = DateTime.Parse(parts[3], culture);
                items.Add(foo);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: public string Names { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public DateTime Joined { get; set; }

Comment: @MartinSahner er... yes?

Comment: It generates an error stating that the get and set methods are not marked extern or abstract and hence should declare a body.

Comment: @MartinSahner and as I already replied elsewhere: please tell us what version of Visual Studio you are using, as that suggests you are using a ***really really*** old version of C#. I have, however, edited in a second version that should work just about anywhere.

Comment: @MartinSahner I can't tell if that question is serious... the job of the compiler is to check whether something is *syntactically valid*, and if so : compile it into IL (in the case of .NET); it might also give you some warnings if it spots obvious errors (trying to use an object that can only possibly be `null`, etc). What it *doesn't* do is check that *you've written the right thing*. Most likely, your file is not, in fact, tab-delimited - in which case you'll need to **change the code** to parse it by column index instead. Use the debugger; press F5 and watch what it does.

Comment: @MartinSahner also, and again: ***which version of Visual Studio are you using***?

Comment: It keeps generating error messages. Please help. Index out of bounds of the array. At Program.ReadFile(string path) and At Program.main

Comment: Marc Gravell, are you there sir?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to retrieve just the dates. You'd probably be better reading your data into Tuples first. Something like

```
List<Tuple<string, int, string, DateTime>> items.
```

Then you can sort them by items.Item4, which will be the date.

Answer (score 0):

get the desired values in Array from the file...

```
public class DateComparer : IComparer {
  public int Compare(DateTime x, DateTime y) {
    if(x.Date > y.Date)
         return 1;
    if(x.Date < y.Date)
         return -1;
    else
         return 0;
  }
}
list.Sort(new DateComparer());
```

Comment: you realise that comparer is malformed? it needs to handle all 3 cases... besides - `return x.CompareTo(y);` or `return y.CompareTo(x);` would be saner. Not to mention that the code *doesn't have `DateTime`s*

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ and split the line according to tabs to only retrieve the date and order them through a conversion to date.

```
while ((linevalue = filereader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
          items.Add(linevalue.Split('\t').Last());
    }
    filereader.Close();
    items.OrderBy(i => DateTime.Parse(i));
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Comment: public string Names { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public DateTime Joined { get; set; } this does not work for me as it keeps stating that i need to declare a body for the get and set methods are not marked abstract or extern

Comment: @MartinSahner I suspect that was intended for my post; that suggests you are using a **very** old version of C# - what version of Visual Studio are you using, so that we can give an appropriate answer?